# Price data from YahooFinance error: TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: NoneType

Tags: python, error-handling, yahoo-finance, nonetype

I have a list of about 250 stock symbols (e.g. 'AAPL', 'IBM', 'QQQ', ...) and try to fetch price data from Yahoo Finance using YahooFinancials.

```
nr_periods = 333

date_N_days_ago = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days = nr_periods)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
date_today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(symbols_list)
hist_prices = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(date_N_days_ago, date_today, 'daily')
```

This code causes the error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: NoneType
```

The problem is that this error message doesn't arise everytime I execute the code but randomly. I couldn't figure out why. Here is the full stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfile.py", line 273, in <module>
    updatePrices(logger)
  File "testfile.py", line 185, in updatePrices
    hist_prices = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(date_N_days_ago, date_today, 'daily')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 547, in get_historical_price_data
    return self.get_stock_data('history', hist_obj=hist_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 428, in get_stock_data
    dict_ent = self._create_dict_ent(tick, statement_type, tech_type, report_name, hist_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 364, in _create_dict_ent
    cleaned_re_data = self._clean_historical_data(re_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 270, in _clean_historical_data
    cleaned_date = self.format_date(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yahoofinancials/__init__.py", line 111, in format_date
    form_date = str((datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_date)).date())
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: NoneType
```

Comment: Full stack trace will help. What line raises that TypeError?

Comment: I tried with a try - except block to catch the error but even this wasn't possible. My code stopped immediately with the error log in the linux terminal instead in my log file.

Comment: Try logging your date_N_days_ago and date_today when you run into an Error. It's either a problem with the yahoo_financials function or the data you send it.

Comment: I do log the date_N_days_ago and date_today. They don't change. I already checked them. It's weird because an hour ago I ran the script - it was fine, then again - it was fine but third time I startet (NO CHANGE at all) it crashed as described.

Comment: Looks like a defect in YahooFinancials to me. Might want to report it to them on their git project.

Answer (score 0):

It was a indeed a defect. The author has fixed it:
https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials